# "she was raped" or "she had been raped" in this reported speech

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, reported-speech, backshifting

> **A)** A 21 year old girl studying in Vidynagar alleged that *she **was** raped* by a boy in a hotel in the city on August 23. Based on above complaint police arrested accuse.
>
> **B)** A 21 year old girl studying in Vidynagar alleged that *she **had been** raped* by a boy in a hotel in the city on August 23. Based on above complaint police arrested accuse.

Which one is more suitable for the reported speech? Why?

Comment: This can help: [Was vs had been](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164870/was-vs-had-been?newreg=da0322c5403b4177a88e7b9e96a46b35)

Comment: ... arrested **the accused**

Comment: @AidenStewart, the element of reported speech makes this different from the linked question.

Comment: @Karl It is not a duplicate. I have posted the link as a resource for help.

Comment: Understood @AidenStewart

Answer (score 1):

Based on the case you present, the girl was raped by a boy in a hotel. That is the correct descriptive statement.

As you note, when this is delivered in reported speech, a conversion takes place, as follows.

Direct Speech: The girl said, "I was raped in a hotel."

Reported Spch: The girl said *that* she *had been* raped in a hotel.

Alleged/said, same principle, these are just reporting verbs. Therefore, the correct sentence from your question is:

> 2. A 21 year old girl studying in Vidynagar *alleged that she had been* raped by a boy in a hotel in the city on August 23. Based on
>      above complaint police arrested **the accused**. (edited for
>      correctness)

I'm not sure if this answers the "why" part of your question, or if you are actually asking why we do this for converted speech.

If the latter, then the reason we do this for reported speech is because there are three events on the timeline:

A––––––––B–––––––––C

A: when the event happened (the rape)

B: when the speech happened (the girl describing her experience)

C: when the report happened (a third party repeating what the girl said)

Since A happened before B, then at time C, we refer to it using Past Perfect.